# Скрыть/показать checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Помогите,пожалуйста, есть код:

```html
<label for="Bort">Борт у стены</label>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" id="Bort" name="cc" />
<label for="Bort2">покраска борта у стены </label>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" id="Bort2" name="cc" />
```

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске страницы был чекбокс: `"Борт у стены"`, а при нажатии на него отображался второй чекбокс `"покраска борта у стены"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#Bort2,
#labelBort2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#Bort:checked~#Bort2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Bort:checked~#labelBort2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label for="Bort">Борт у стены</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Bort" name="cc" />
<label for="Bort2" id="labelBort2">покраска борта у стены </label>
<input type="checkbox"  id="Bort2" name="cc" />
```

Comment: отлично!Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста....

Comment: С наступающим праздником)))не знаю у вас там празднуют 23 февраля?

Comment: Не празднуют, но внимание всегда приятно, благодарю....